# Swift - isUserInteractionEnabled = false but enable 2 gestures

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, user-interaction, setuserinteractionenabled

I would like to block interactions with users, with the exception of the double tap for cancel.
Is it possible to put *isUserInteractionEnabled = false* **and** an exception rule for my double tap lines below ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PostlistViewController.handleTap(_:)))
    tapGR.delegate = self
    tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)
}
```

--

```
extension MainBoardController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("doubletapped")
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run your app and see what happens?

Comment: If you're setting `numberOfTapsRequired` to 2 I believe that should be already enough to apply the 2 tap constraint. Remember to set `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` to make the gesture recognizer work.

Comment: The fact is that I launch a firebase upload of a file.
I use a spinner to indicate the progress of the upload and I disable the userinteraction but I just want the double tap to work, to cancel the uploading of the file.